# Create dataframe using groupby of percentage with condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to create a dataframe in pandas to create a seaborn bar plot. My problem is I am not able to groupby the data with string column. If I use value_count() function it, work fine but in dataframe. Below is the detail explaination: -

My data is

```
Data_Hr = {"Age": [41,49,37,33,27], "Attrition": ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"], "ageRange":[ 40-45 45-50 35-40 30-35 25-30]
```

Now I want to calculate % of Attrition with "Yes" value groupby "ageRange". Below is the function I am using but it is not converted into dataframe.

```
df[df.Attrition == 'Yes']['ageRange'].value_counts()/df['ageRange'].value_counts()*100
```

Or any other method to plot the graph of attrition%.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine.
Please note that the last list is without '' and without commas. You should change it to:

```
Data_Hr = {"Age": [41,49,37,33,27], "Attrition": ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"], "ageRange":['40-45', '45-50', '35-40', '30-35', '25-30']}
```

Then if you want to plot a graph from the results you should format the results as a dataframe:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(df[df.Attrition == 'Yes']['ageRange'].value_counts()/df['ageRange'].value_counts()*100)
results .dropna(subset=['ageRange'], inplace=True)
```

And to display using `seaborn`:

```
 sns.barplot(data = results, x = 'ageRange', y = results.index, color = 'Blue').set_title('Age Range Count of Attrition')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but then what is the issue for creating a barplot in seaborn? I am using below code :
sns.barplot(x='ageRange', y=(100*df[df.Attrition == 'Yes']['ageRange'].value_counts()/df['ageRange'].value_counts()), data=df)

Comment: See updated answer above

Comment: Thanks again, but problem remains. I am able to create plt.plot using the code but not seaborn. See below example 
Working well(plt.plot):   (100*df[df.Attrition == 'Yes']['Department'].value_counts()/df['Department'].value_counts()).plot(kind='bar',color='blue')
Not working  : - 
results = pd.DataFrame(df[df.Attrition == 'Yes']['ageRange'].value_counts()/df['ageRange'].value_counts()*100)
results .dropna(subset=['ageRange'], inplace=True)
sns.barplot(data = results, x = 'ageRange', y = 'ageRange', color = 'Blue',order = ageRange_order).set_title('Age Range Count of Attrition')

Comment: See updated answer above